# Would it be polite to ask the graduate program coordinator if my PhD application made the shortlist?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, program-committee

I recently submitted an application to a certain PhD program at a certain university. According the university's website and the graduate program coordinator, the graduate admissions committee will meet this mid-February to make a shortlist of applicants who will qualify for the next round of screening. The final result of the application will be available in mid-April. Now, if my application doesn't make the shortlist, obviously, there's no chance of me getting an admission offer in April. It thought, then, that it might be a good idea to know in February if I was shortlisted, so I could make new plans ahead of time in case I didn't get admitted. But is it polite to ask the graduate program coordinator in February if I was shortlisted?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask, but it's unlikely they will give you an answer until they send out their final decisions to everyone in April.  Given that, I'd be inclined not to ask out of concern they might see it as pestering or pressuring.